# How to make a loop to find string that matches

Tags: vb.net

Hi I want to extract all string that matches this code:

```
        Dim textafter As String = """,""webPageType"
        Dim textbefore As String = """url"":""/watch?v="
        Dim startPosition As Integer = RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(textbefore)
        startPosition += textbefore.Length
        Dim endPosition As Integer = RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(textafter, startPosition)
        Dim textFound As String = RichTextBox1.Text.Substring(startPosition, endPosition - startPosition)
        RichTextBox1.Text = (textFound)
```

This code is giving back the first url that is matching. How can I use a for each to retrieve all link that matches my criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use a *regular expression* to find matches to a pattern made from the beginning text plus anything plus the ending text.

As an example, the following code makes up some test data, and uses a regex to get the data you're after. It just needs two RichTextBox controls, named rtbSource and rtbFound.

```
Option Strict On

Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1

    Function FindDelimitedStrings(sourceText As String, textBefore As String, textAfter As String) As List(Of String)
        Dim found As New List(Of String)
        Dim re = New Regex(Regex.Escape(textBefore) & "(.*?)" & Regex.Escape(textAfter), RegexOptions.Singleline)
        Dim ms = re.Matches(sourceText)
        For Each m As Match In ms
            found.Add(m.Groups(1).Value)
        Next

        Return found

    End Function

    Sub AddTestData(textBefore As String, textAfter As String)
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

        For Each w In {"A", "B", "C"}
            sb.AppendLine(textBefore & w & textAfter)
            sb.AppendLine("---")
        Next
        rtbSource.Text = sb.ToString()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim textBefore As String = """url"":""/watch?v="
        Dim textAfter As String = """,""webPageType"

        AddTestData(textBefore, textAfter)

        For Each s In FindDelimitedStrings(rtbSource.Text, textBefore, textAfter)
            rtbFound.AppendText(s & vbCrLf)
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

The `.*?` in the regex matches any character between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (explanation from https://regex101.com). The parentheses tell it to put it into a group. The `Regex.Escape` is to make sure that any characters which have a special meaning in a regex are escaped so they lose their special meaning.

The above code shows this in rtbSource:

```
"url":"/watch?v=A","webPageType
---
"url":"/watch?v=B","webPageType
---
"url":"/watch?v=C","webPageType
---
```

and puts this in rtbFound:

```
A
B
C
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but I just want to show the url,  in this case A, b c etc, without "url":"/watch?v= and "webpagetype.. is this possible?

Comment: What you mean with " for each w in A, B, C? It s plenty of links that matches in there, not just three.. Am I wrong?

Comment: @34234234 That was just test data to demonstrate, as I don't have access to the actual data you're using.

Comment: The number of links that matches my criteria are unrefined.. it can be 10 or 500.. that s why i m doubting about this system.

Comment: Something like "for each url that match my criteria then show in rtb1 the list of them..

Comment: @34234234 You can ignore the test data and the For loop used to create it. Use your own data.

Comment: I m parsing a youtube playlist, that s why the number of url founda is a variable

Comment: The number of found URLs makes no difference to the `FindDelimitedStrings` function ;)

Comment: Oh right, so you are suggesting me to ignore sub testdata , am I wrong? Thanks

Comment: I woule like to take advantage of the situation to ask you if, In this case, can I parse also all titles by just adding the same written code for urls  also for titles? I Will take the html to scrap title too. Would this work?

Comment: @34234234 I think you're asking if you can use different strings for the `textBefore` and `textAfter` parameters in the `FindDelimitedStrings` function: yes, you can.

Comment: Great! i'm parsing the titles, but sometimes I can see  "\u0026" instead of Ampersands (&) . I've tried to replace that with nothing with:  `For Each m As Match In ms
            m.ToString.Replace(" \u0026 ", "&")
            found.Add(m.Groups(1).Value)
        Next`
but it doesn't do anything. It gives back the titles with that, and it gives no errors. I'm expecting to read strings replaced " \u0026 " with &

Comment: I found!  s = s.Replace("\u0026", "&")